# How to add elements to a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I've looked around on the internet a bit and cannot seem to find the answer to this question.  I want to declare a vector in matlab and then have a for loop that will add an element to the vector each time I go through the for loop.

This is what I've tried and it doesn't seem to be working

```
vector[];

for k = 1 ; 10
%calculate some value
%calculated value stored in temp variable
vector(k) = temp;
end
```

This does not work. Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: it is `for k = 1:10`. And it should work like this. You don't need to declare the vector variable upfront. You should also describe what errornous output / error message you are getting.

Comment: Thanks I didn't need to declare the vector at the top

Answer (score 1):

As ypnos said, you don't need to declare the vector variable upfront. For example if you did:

```
vector(50) = 1;
```

MATLAB would make a vector of length 50 with the 50th value being 1. If you want to improve performance and want to create a vector of the proper size beforehand then do the following:

```
vector = zeros(10, 1);
```

The code as you have it (as long as you fix the loop as ypnos said) will work, except for how you declare vector, which is not correct. I bet you are getting the error message: `"Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket."` You do not specify whether a variable is a matrix/vector in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector = [vector; temp];
```

or

```
vector(end+1) = temp;
```